# Git setup in the middle of a project

Tags: git

I'm working on a projet that has lasted for several years, and we want to manage it more completely with Git.

The overview of the project layout is as follows:

- **There is one team (let's call it Bob) in charge of producing a software**, with new versions every once in a while; Bob uses SVN internally to manage its codebase.
- **There is a second team (let's call it Marie), sort of the 'customer'** : she uses the sofware produced by Bob, and tweaks it to her needs, by modifying some files provided by Bob, and adding extra files. Sometimes, Maries modifies something that should be integrated back by Bob in the next version of the software. **Marie uses Git** to track her own changes. Marie is not interested in the low-level code modifications made by Bob (registered by SVN), only in the full versions he provides.

**What we would like to do is to add a branch to Marie's git repository where we can import Bob's new versions and then, after each new version, merge from this branch to Marie's, in order to cleanly import changes brought by this new version.**

However, since Marie files and Bob's have diverged I do not know how to start: if I create Bob's branch from Marie's, I will have to make a first commit to get back into Bob's current state (i.e. clean software without **Marie**'s modifications); the issue is that this commit will be taken into account in the subsequent merge from Bob's branch to Marie's even though we don't want it.

How could we proceed to ovecome this issue?

Comment: Why is Marie using git instead of SVN? I don't feel like Bob should be responsible for integrating these changes if they come from a different source control tool. Maybe I don't see the bigger picture fully

Comment: Bob is not reponsible for anything in what we want to achieve. He will still use SVN and produce new versions of the software as he always did. Still, Marie wants to be able to easily integrate in her current workspace the diffs generated by Bob's new versions without having to look at all files one by one, thus a typical use case for a git branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

Have all progress made by Bob in master branch commits. Master branch is like

```
Bob's release 1  ---  Bob's release 2  ---  Bob's release 3 --- ...
```

Put Marie's changes to separate branch that is derived from the most recent Bob's release:

```
Bob's release 1  ---  Bob's release 2  ---  Bob's release 3 --- ...
                                                  |
                                          Marie's adjustments
```

When Bob makes new release, I would commit it to the master, create new branch from previous Marie's branch and rebase it on the most recent master (`git checkout Marie1 && git checkout -b Marie2 && git rebase master`):

```
Bob1 --- Bob2  --- Bob3 --- Bob4 ---
                     |        |
                  Marie1   Marie2
```

By this way, you have track of all Bob's releases and also Marie's adjustments for every single of these (I would unify naming of Bob's commit e.g. `Bob v1.0.1` and respective Marie's branch e.g. `marie_v1.0.1`). In addition, interactive rebase can help with picking only some of adjustments in the new release, copying also enables you to keep the old versions of Marie's adjustments and also have more different branches `marie_v1.0.1_variant_x`, `marie_v1.0.1_variant_y`... derived from single Bob's release.